# Parsing a script?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parsing

I'm used to parsing XML to display data in apps, but now I'm dealing with a source that's in the form of an embedded snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&cat=0-29&date=today+7-d&cmpt=q&content=1&cid=RISING_QUERIES_0_0&export=5&w=300&h=420"></script>
```

How can I parse this? I'm just trying to get the first item on the list and the value associated with it. I found a few things about data scrapping - but then I'll have to put up a site just to scrape it? There must be a better way.

Any help is really appreciated. Thx! Antoine

Comment: You want to parse something out of the URL? Or the javascript stored there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[www.google.com/trends/embed.js](http://www.google.com/trends/embed.js) is a javascript which just does a `document.write function`. there is no way to parse that! if you want to parse the iframe which is written to the page, you need to open the page (you could do it with `node.js` and `phantom.js`)